# Add a caption to anchor tag in html <a href="" target="">"Is a +<b?"</a>

Tags: html

```
<html>
<a href="" target="">"Is a +<b?"</a>
</html
```

what is the output? For me its coming Is a +

Comment: what you are trying to achieve ? i mean what you are expecting ?

Comment: "<" this is anchor tag and it things it's a tag you are using. That's why it won't display

Comment: your html tag is not closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the less than sign to display you need to convert it to an [HTML entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity), otherwise the browser interprets it as part of an element. In this case change the `<` to `&lt;`

Ex:

```html
<a href="" target="">"Is a +&lt;b?"</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `<` to an HTML entity.

```html
<html>
    <a href="" target="" id="is">"Is a +&lt;b?"</a>
</html>
```

If you are using JavaScript, you can use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode characters:

```js
document.getElementById("is").innerHTML = encodeURIComponent('"Is a +<b?"');
```

If you are using PHP, you can use `urlencode()` to encode characters:

```php
<?php echo encodeurl('"Is a +<b?"');?>
```

Also, your HTML code syntax is incorrect. Please run your code through an [XHTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/).